# Is there a measure of satiety?

Tags: nutrition

I know that fibre is apparently meant to make you feel more 'full' but some foods have no fibre and you can still feel full after eating those.

So are there any measures for how full different foods make you?

I'm wondering if satiety is determined mostly by the volume of the food, or perhaps the chewed volume, by certain nutrients (such as fibre), or what else could it be. Or even a subjective score given to different foods in some sort of study.

Answer (score -2):

Benefit of fibers is mostly that fibers are not absorbed by your organism, and henceforth remain in your intestine during the digestion process, as well as filling your stomach, which can possibly delay somewhat the hungry feeling.

Now, there are also (mainly I guess) hormones. [Leptin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptin) or [Ghrelin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghrelin) are examples of these. The reason why it is often to recommended to take your time while eating (about 20min) is to let hormone regulation occur.

PS: some people with genetics disorder with these hormones can have problems with obesity.